# while loop causing crash

Tags: java, while-loop, freeze

```
boolean bury = false;
long lastAction = 0;
if (inputString.startsWith("::bury")) {
    bury = !bury; 
    while (bury) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAction > 500) {
            stream.createFrame(122);
            stream.method433(atInventoryInterface);
            stream.method432(0);
            stream.method431(Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(7))); // Item ID
            lastAction = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm playing a game, sending bogus packets to make my life easier like any kid would. The problem is, having an autotyper send the command for me prevents me from chatting with other players.

That's where the while loop comes in. I'm attempting to put the code in an infinite loop (calling the code every half second), but when I attempt the process, the entire game freezes.

I admit, I've never used a while loop before so perhaps I just don't understand it well enough, but it should be working, no?

Comment: Just as an aside, there is a difference between a crash and a freeze. A crash tends to imply an error being thrown, a freeze is a program not responding.

Comment: Putting the code in an infinite loop will not let the rest of the game engine to run unless it's done on another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this while loop in a new Thread. Seems your loop is inside the main Thread and so the infinite loop stops the whole program.

Comment: new Thread: okay. But don't loop for busy waiting. Use Thread#sleep at least.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this on the main event handling thread in a GUI application.
All methods there are supposed to do something and return quickly, so that the UI can redraw and other events can be dispatched.

What you are looking for is a Timer that does some repeated work at a schedule. Your GUI framework should offer a facility to manage those.

Those timers also avoid the need for "busy waiting", which is what your loop is doing. Even if blocking the rest of the world would not be a problem, it's a tremendous waste of CPU (and electricity). Instead of looking at the time every nanosecond or so in a tight loop, you can schedule a timer for "in 500 milliseconds".

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `sleep(0.5)` to slow down the loop.

Comment: but _"I'm attempting to put the code in an infinite loop"_

Comment: infinite loop freezes your program! It freezes every program! Unless you put a delay in there than can reduce the speed of it running.

Comment: Okay, yes. I thought it was necessary in order to be able to kill the process. If i just used `System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAction > 500`, I wouldn't have any input as to when it shuts down. Right?

Comment: Well of course I need a delay, that's why I'm using `System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAction > 500` that way, it doesn't do anything until that parameter is met.

Comment: You should run it on a background thread, and use `sleep(0.5)` to make sure it runs only every 0.5 seconds. With what you have, it runs at max speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.sleep(500);` for making thread sleep for half a second. instead of loop. but the problem is somewhere else !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code running in an infinite loop into some background thread, different from the main thread where the rest of the code is running and then obtain the results from that.